# How can I change a list item class via state in React progressively

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state here that contains text for every page:

```
this.state = {
  page: 0,
  weight: 'normal'
}
```

So whenever the button next was being click, the content for that specific page is being loaded.

```
movePage() {
    this.setState({ page: +this.state.page + 1 });
  }
```

Let's say for page 1 I have a h1 tag saying that this is page 1 and on page 2 I have h2 saying that this is the page 2 and so forth.

However, I also have a list of navigation that I need to change the font weight via weight state.

So basically the font weight className default is normal which is:

```
.normal{
  font-weight: normal
}
```

But whenever the next button is being click the list item for that page must change it's class to 'bold'

```
.bold{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

How do I access the className for each item and change each item's className progressively using both state while moving from page 1 to 3?

```
const list = (props) => {
  return(
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" className="{this.state.weight}">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" className="{this.state.weight}">Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" className="{this.state.weight}">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
)

}
```

For instance:

```
if(this.state.page === 1){
  this.setState({
    weight: 'bold'
  })
}
```

However this one will not work as it is only limited to one page but this must dynamically change each list item class per page. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this code will help you. it will add class to link as per your page

```
const list = props => {
 const page = this.state.page;
  return (
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#" className={page >= 1 ? "bold": "normal"}>Page 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" className={page >= 2 ? "bold": "normal"}>Page 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" className={page >= 3 ? "bold": "normal"}>Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  )
}
```

or you can do more dynamic way

```
const list = props => {
  const page = this.state.page;
  const pages = ["page 1", "page 2", "page 3", "page 4"];
  return (
       <ul>
        {pages.map((item, index) => <li key={index}><a href="#" className={page >= index + 1 ? 'bold' : 'normal'}>{item}</a></li>)}
      </ul>
  )
}
```

Comment: how can i set a default class then? let's say "normal" class?

Comment: basically I just want to overwrite the existing class of the list item whenever the page is equal to the page number

Comment: but it must leave the previous bold class then

Comment: add this code `<li><a href="#" className={page == 1 ? "bold": "normal"}>Page 1</a></li>` it set default class normal

Comment: Hi again paterarpan, yeah I undestand this but what I am saying is that whenever it passes each list item it must retain that bold class and must not put back to the default normal class? Let's say i click on the next button for page 2 so the bold class must be on both page 1 and page not only on page 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169497/discussion-between-patelarpan-and-tony-beatty).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build something based on pages you may have a look at

[react-transition-handler](https://github.com/antoniopangallo/react-transition-handler)